# No results for AND operator in sql query

Tags: mysql

Why am i not getting answer if i use and operator in my query?

**MY TABLE**

```
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| course_id | sec_id | semester | year | building | room_number | time_slot_id |
| BIO-301   | 1      | Summer   | 2010 | Painter  | 514         | A            |
| CS-101    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 | Packard  | 101         | H            |
| CS-101    | 1      | Spring   | 2010 | Packard  | 101         | F            |
| CS-190    | 1      | Spring   | 2009 | Taylor   | 3128        | E            |
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

**SQL QUERY WITH OUTPUT**

```
MariaDB [university2038]> 

    select course_id from section where semester='Fall' AND semester='Spring';

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: *"semester='Fall' AND semester='Spring'"* -- how can be the value of `semester` both "Fall" and "Spring" at the same time?

Comment: CS-101 is course_id which belongs to both semester and if we use or operator then we will get CS-101 and CS-190 but this is not right output

Comment: You didn't post the requirement, you posted only the query. Based on the query you got the answers. If the answers do not solve your problem it's because you didn't post the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE semester='Fall' AND semester='Spring'` will always result in no rows because a cell cannot be the value 'Fall' AND the value 'Spring' at the same time. You are looking for the `OR` condition.

Answer (score 2):

> semester='Fall' AND semester='Spring'

How can be the value of `semester` both "Fall" and "Spring" at the same time?

This is a common error that emerges from the sloppiness of the spoken language. We say *"I want to get the courses scheduled during the next spring AND fall".*

But the logical (boolean) conditions behind this statement are "the courses that are scheduled *during the spring* **OR** *during the fall*".

One can express this in SQL as:

```
SELECT course_id FROM section WHERE semester = 'Fall' OR semester = 'Spring'
```

A shorter (and easier to understand) way to write the same thing is achieved using the [`IN` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT course_id FROM section WHERE semester IN ('Fall', 'Spring')
```

Comment: i wanna find course_id which are offered in both 'Fall' and 'Spring' semester

Comment: Update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually said what you want the outlook to look like so any of the following may be appropriate.

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists p;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table p
    -> ( course_id VARCHAR(10), sec_id INT, semester VARCHAR(100), year INT, building VARCHAR(10), room_number INT, time_slot_id varchar(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>  insert into p values
    -> ( 'BIO-301'   , 1      , 'Summer'   , 2010 , 'Painter'  , 514         , 'A'),
    -> ( 'CS-101'    , 1      , 'Fall'     , 2009 , 'Packard'  , 101         , 'H'),
    -> ( 'CS-101'    , 1      , 'Spring'   , 2010 , 'Packard'  , 101         , 'F'),
    -> ( 'CS-190'    , 1      , 'Spring'   , 2009 , 'Taylor'   , 3128        , 'E');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT COURSE_ID
    -> FROM   P
    -> WHERE SEMESTER IN ('Fall','Spring')
    -> GROUP BY COURSE_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
+-----------+
| COURSE_ID |
+-----------+
| CS-101    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select *
    -> from p
    -> where course_id in
    -> (SELECT COURSE_ID
    -> FROM   P
    -> WHERE SEMESTER IN ('Fall','Spring')
    -> GROUP BY COURSE_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    -> )
    -> ;
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| course_id | sec_id | semester | year | building | room_number | time_slot_id |
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| CS-101    |      1 | Fall     | 2009 | Packard  |         101 | H            |
| CS-101    |      1 | Spring   | 2010 | Packard  |         101 | F            |
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select p.*
    -> from p
    -> join
    -> (select course_id,
    -> sum(case when semester in('Spring','Fall') then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
    -> from p
    -> group by course_id
    -> ) s
    -> on s.course_id = p.course_id
    -> where s.cnt = 2
    -> ;
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| course_id | sec_id | semester | year | building | room_number | time_slot_id |
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| CS-101    |      1 | Fall     | 2009 | Packard  |         101 | H            |
| CS-101    |      1 | Spring   | 2010 | Packard  |         101 | F            |
+-----------+--------+----------+------+----------+-------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```